# Where to specify preprocessor directives in visual studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

Trying to define a preprocessor directives in the Visual studio 2012.

```
#define FLAG
....
#endif
```

But not sure, where to include this `FLAG` in visual studio - C#. I remember specifying something like this in C++ projects.

Any thoughts ?

Comment: They're called "preprocessor directives" anyway, even though the compiler doesn't have a preprocessor.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ed8yd1ha.aspx

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You have two options as to where to define it:

1. **Code file level** - In the beginning of the file write `#define FLAG`. You cannot place anything else (other than comments and blank lines) before `define` directives. As Ron Beyer points out, *a directive defined in a file exists only for that file*.
2. **Project level** - Right click in the project in Solution Explorer, select `Properties`, then the `Build` tab, then look at `Conditional compilation symbols`. Then one can define several comma-separated symbols there such as: `FLAG,FOO,BAR`. Note that this symbols list is project configuration dependent (there is a configuration selector in the same tab).

---

Note as mentioned in the comments, `define` does not work in C# the same way that it does in C. In C# you just declare that the symbol exists, but you can't assign a value to it. Hence the only use for these symbols is for `#if FLAG` directives and for [the Conditional attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.conditionalattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: You should note that defining it at the code file level only defines the flag for that code file, it doesn't do it project wide. Its a departure from how C++ works.

Comment: Also note, you cannot specify *values* for these definitions. You can only specify *the definition itself.*

Comment: if you define it at the project level, where does VS store that info? I can't find it in the .csproj or .sln files, and I don't seem to be able to remove it

Comment: @mcmillab it's in the .csproj under \Project\PropertyGroup\DefineConstants

Comment: In my version of VS 2022 Pro v 17.7.5 there is no "Build" tab under "Solution Explorer" / Properties.  There are no ".csproj" files anywhere in the project directory structure.

Answer (score 2):

For some reason, when properties clicked, nothing happened for me. So I did the following. And it worked.

Open your csproj project file using text editor and  add your preprocessor compiler directives in between these.
<DefineConstants>
HERE!!!
</DefineConstants>