# Defining C# preprocessor directive at the Solution level

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, project, solution, preprocessor-directive

I have a question [Based on This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30350738/where-to-specify-preprocessor-directives-in-visual-studio)

Is it possible in C# to define a preprocessor directive at the solution level rather than the project level.

Motivation:  I have a common library, and there are two solutions that need it.  I want the preprocessor directive to be present in one, and not the other, but since the library is at the project level, if I define the preprocessor directive at the project level, this obviously won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a [`Directory.Build.props`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-your-build?view=vs-2022#directorybuildprops-and-directorybuildtargets) file, and put it at the root of your solution. Inside the file you can specify  [`DefineConstants`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/language#defineconstants) option:

```
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <DefineConstants>MY_DIRECTIVE</DefineConstants>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```